# Echo an external javascript function using php on an uploaded file extention check

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

I'm trying to have a javascript alert pop up if a user's uploaded file is not of type 'kml' or 'json'.

My code for the file check is

```
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$allowed = array('kml', 'json');
if( ! in_array( $ext, $allowed ) ) {echo 'run()';}
```

where `run()` is just a JavaScript alert and is in a seperate file in the same directory and is included in the index header.

Is there a better way to go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: I think is way is good enough.

Comment: Should this go before or after my upload funtion? Because right now it causes my project to crash with no error

Comment: before upload. what do you mean by project crashing?

Comment: Well my project has to do with geospatial data so I am using OpenLayers Maps, when I have this code saved in the file the map doesn't display anymore while the rest of the project does for some reason